# React-Native New Project setup Error in version 0.70

Tags: ruby, react-native, gemfile

```
  ######                ######               
             ###     ####        ####     ###             
            ##          ###    ###          ##            
            ##             ####             ##            
            ##             ####             ##            
            ##           ##    ##           ##            
            ##         ###      ###         ##            
             ##  ########################  ##             
          ######    ###            ###    ######          
      ###     ##    ##              ##    ##     ###      
   ###         ## ###      ####      ### ##         ###   
  ##           ####      ########      ####           ##  
 ##             ###     ##########     ###             ## 
  ##           ####      ########      ####           ##  
   ###         ## ###      ####      ### ##         ###   
      ###     ##    ##              ##    ##     ###      
          ######    ###            ###    ######          
             ##  ########################  ##             
            ##         ###      ###         ##            
            ##           ##    ##           ##            
            ##             ####             ##            
            ##             ####             ##            
            ##          ###    ###          ##            
             ###     ####        ####     ###             
               ######                ######               
                                                          

                  Welcome to React Native!                
                 Learn once, write anywhere               

✔ Downloading template
✔ Copying template
✔ Processing template
✖ Installing Bundler
error Your Ruby version is 3.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.7.5

✖ Installing Bundler
error Error: Looks like your iOS environment is not properly set. Please go to https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/environment-setup and follow the React Native CLI QuickStart guide for macOS and iOS.
```

I was trying to setup new project in react native as i have latest macOS ventura 13.0 and xcode(Version 14.0.1 (14A400)

follow: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup
and some other solution as well but didn't work.
please help

Answer (score 3):

it seems there a conflict with your ruby version, you can downgrade to the ruby version specified on the error message. To do that follow the steps:

1. Download some Ruby version manager like rvm

```bash
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

2. Install the version of ruby 2.7.5

```bash
rvm install 2.7.5
```

try create your react-native project again!